# Find the Limits Of Complex Functions

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

$$\lim_{z\to \infty}\frac{3z^2 + 2z - i}{2iz^2 - 1}$$

Attempt:
I replaced z with 1/z and solved it. I got this $$\lim_{z\to \infty}\frac {2i-z^2}{3+2z-iz^2}$$

Comment: Why did the ratio get "flipped over"?  Also, if you've transformed the variable to $ \ \frac{1}{z} \ $ , wouldn't the limit now goes to _zero_?  (But you needn't have gone to the trouble -- this limit works the same way that it would for a real variable rational function...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two mistakes: if you replace $z$ with $1/z$ you get:

$$\lim_{\frac{1}{z}\to \infty}\frac{3(\frac{1}{z})^2 + 2\frac{1}{z} - i}{2i(\frac{1}{z})^2 - 1}=\lim_{z\to {\color{red}0}}\frac{3 + 2z - iz^2}{2i - z^2}=\dfrac{3}{2i}=-\dfrac{3}{2}i$$

You could also have taken the dominant term of the numerator and denominator: $3$ and $2i$, but maybe you have not studied that yet (to use only when you really understand what you're doing).